# unchecked call to setClass(Class<T>)as a member of the raw type

Tags: java, android

Im trying to write a universal asyncTask for more requests

```
public class AsyncTaskInner <T> extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<T>> {

    Class<T> mClazz;

    public void setDataListener(TimeDataListener dataListener) {
        mDataListener = dataListener;
    }
    public void setClass(Class<T> clazz){
        mClazz = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    protected final List<T> doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        String path = "";
        final String requestItem = Config.getTime();
        List<T> priceResponseList = null;

        path = Config.getPath();

        try {
            URL url = new URL(path);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            final int statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();

            if (statusCode == 200) {  // 200 -> STATUS_OK.

                InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                String response = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, "UTF-8");
                priceResponseList = getTimeResponse(response, mClazz);
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return priceResponseList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<T> priceResponceList) {
        super.onPostExecute(priceResponceList);
        if (priceResponceList != null) {
            mDataListener.onTimeDataReceived(priceResponceList);
        }
    }
}
```

it's returned error on **setClass()** method and on **.execute()**...
unchecked call to **setClass(Class)** as a member of the raw type RequestFactory.AsyncTaskInner
unchecked call to **'execute(Params)'** as a member of row type 'android.os.AsyncTask'

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Comment: Can you please provide code that creates and calls this async task?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I just should write that
RequestFactory.AsyncTaskInner<**TimeResponce**> timeRequest;

```
timeRequest = new RequestFactory().new AsyncTaskInner<>();
timeRequest.setClass(TimeResponce.class);
timeRequest.execute();
```